# center of mass in each cell of N-dimensional rectilinear grid

Tags: python, math, geometry, numerical-methods

I have an n-Dimensional rectilinear grid, such that the edges in each dimension i are given by `x_i = {x[i, 0], x[i,1], ..., x[i, Ni-1], x[i, Ni]}`, with `N_i` edges in that dimension.  I then have some density `y`, with shape `(N0, N1, ... Ni, ... Nn-1)` defined at each grid vertex.  We can assume that the density varies smoothly, and the density between vertices (i.e. within a cell) can be calculated by smoothly (linearly) interpolating between vertices.  How do I find the center of mass in each dimension, for each cell/bin?

Note that the answer is *not* just the y-weighted average of the edges of each bin.  For example, consider a 2D grid with x-coordinates `[0.0, 1.0]`, and a density `[[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 2.0]]`.  The y-weighted x position of vertices is 1.0, but clearly the center of mass needs to be somewhere mid-way between the edges, not up against the edge:

```
0.0--------2.0  -y2
 |          |
 |        * |
 |          |
 |          |
 |          |
0.0--------1.0  -y1

 |        |
 x1=0.0   x2=1.0
```

where the * approximates the center of mass.

Comment: *"but clearly the center of mass needs to be somewhere mid-way between the edges, not up against the edge:"* I don't understand this sentence?

Comment: Is mass distributed on edges only?

Comment: @Stef The density smoothly varies across the bin.  There is higher density to the right, so the center of mass will be nearer the right-side, but because there is non-zero density to the left of the right-edge, the center of mass will not be exactly on the right-edge.

Comment: @MBo no, there is a smooth density field that's samples at the bin edges, and we can assume it varies linearly between vertices.  I tried to clarify the question as such

Comment: So mass is distributed over cell interior? Note that there is no unified formula to determine  density in inner points using vertice values. Simple example - [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) but there is a list of other methods at the end of that page. In any case  - to get mass center, you have to perform integration of density (either over edges or over all the rectangle).

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume that density is distributed over cell using [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) with normalized cell coordinates `0..1` and vertices values `f[ij]`. Every real cell coordinates might be normalized to the range above using  linear transformation (subtract left bottom coordinate, divide by size).

To get mass center coordinates, we must apply the next formula

[image]

[image]

Practically: for 2D case we calculate denominator ("mass") as definite double integral of `density(x,y)` over `x=0..1` and `y=0..1` ranges and two nominators (vector components) as integrals of `density(x,y)*x` and `density(x,y)*y`. (3D (and nD) cases in vector form look similar, but formulae become more complex.)

Evaluation of these integrals using Maple gives the next result:

[image]

which might be easily  implemented in Python as code below:

```
def mass_center_bilinear(f00, f10, f01, f11):
    mass = 1/4*f00+1/4*f10+1/4*f01+1/4*f11
    if mass == 0:
        return None
    x_int = 1/12*f00+1/6*f10+1/12*f01+1/6*f11
    y_int = 1/12*f00+1/12*f10+1/6*f01+1/6*f11
    return (x_int/mass, y_int/mass)

print(mass_center_bilinear(1,1,1,1))
print(mass_center_bilinear(0,0,0,1))
print(mass_center_bilinear(0,0,1,1))
print(mass_center_bilinear(0,1,2,3))
print(mass_center_bilinear(0,1,0,2))

(0.5, 0.5)
(0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666)
(0.5, 0.6666666666666666)
(0.5555555555555555, 0.611111111111111)
(0.6666666666666666, 0.5555555555555555)  #mass center for your example
```